# Calling next(generatorObject) after print(list(generatorObject) throws a StopIteration exception

Tags: python-3.x, sequence-generators

While using a generator, I noticed that if execute the following code, it throws a StopIteration exception :

```
evenIntegers = even_integers_generator(10)
print(list(evenIntegers))
for i in range(5):
    print(next(evenIntegers))
```

Does anyone know why? I thought that the pointer for the object might be at the end of the iterator but I also tried printing the first item only and it still throws the same error.

Comment: From what I understand, the StopIteration is thrown when the generator has exhausted.

Comment: when you pass `evenIntegers` to list it will consume all the items in the geneartor to build the list. So there will be no more items to iterate in the generator

Comment: remember that a generator can only be iterated over once. So you give it to list and it iterates over it consuming all the items, so not the generator is empty, so when you then try to use the for loop and call next on the generator you get a stop iteration exception since there is nothing left in the generator as list consumed it all